# Laravel Backpack Entering a New Time Field Starts Calendar at 1970

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-backpack

Created a Event CRUD object in Laravel Backpack. Everytime I add a new Event, the calendar that helps set the time for the event is set to 1/1/1970 12:00 AM. How would I change that field to be defaulted to current day 12:00 AM by default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) For the [`datetime` field type](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#section-datetime): if you define `default`, that value will be used. So you can do this:

```
$this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'datetime',
            'label' => 'Datetime',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'default' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        ]);
```

2) For the [`datetime_picker` field type](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#section-datetime_picker), the current date will be prepopulated automatically.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
        $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'datetime',
            'label' => 'Date Time',
            'type' => "datetime_picker",  //use this instead of datetime
            'format' => 'M d,Y H:m',
            'default' => date("Y-m-d 00:00:00"),  //defaults to today at midnight
            'allows_null' => true  //if you want to allow removal of date picked
        ]);
```